# When dropdown value change price will change

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I have working on one ecommerce application. in that application I want when my dropdown value change also my price will change. I am fresher so I don't know how to do this. below is my code. I am combine the pack size and uom two variable in one string  and i also want when my selected dropdown values change  only uom can be store in variable because i want uom to send data to database through api.

1.dropdown code.

```
  List<String> combinedStrings =ProductDetailsUtils.generateCombinedStrings(productDetailsList).where((value) => value.isNotEmpty).toList();
             String  _selectedOption =combinedStrings.isNotEmpty? combinedStrings.first:'';

 DropdownButton<String>(
                                                hint: const Text('__Pack Size__'),
                                                value: _selectedOption,
                                                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                                                underline: Container(
                                                  height: 2,
                                                  color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                                                ),
                                                items:combinedStrings.map((String value) {
                                                       return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                                    value: value,
                                                    child: Text(value),
                                                     );
                                                 }).toList(),
                                                onChanged: (value) {
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    _selectedOption = value!;
                                                  });
                                                },
                                              ),
```

2.productutils

```
class ProductDetailsUtils {
  String? id;
  String? img;
  String? item;
  String? category;
  String? type;
  String? description;
  String? price;
  String? uom;
  String? psize;
  String? price2;
  String? uom2;
  String? psize2;
  String? price3;
  String? uom3;
  String? psize3;
  String? vusername;
  String? displayname;
  String? instock;
  ProductDetailsUtils(
      {this.id,
        this.img,
        this.item,
        this.category,
        this.type,
        this.description,
        this.price,
        this.uom,
        this.psize,
        this.price2,
        this.uom2,
        this.psize2,
        this.price3,
        this.uom3,
        this.psize3,
        this.vusername,
        this.displayname,
        this.instock});

  ProductDetailsUtils.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    img = json['img'];
    item = json['item'];
    category = json['category'];
    type = json['type'];
    description = json['description'];
    price = json['price'];
    uom = json['uom'];
    psize = json['psize'];
    price2 = json['price2'];
    uom2 = json['uom2'];
    psize2 = json['psize2'];
    price3 = json['price3'];
    uom3 = json['uom3'];
    psize3 = json['psize3'];
    vusername = json['vusername'];
    displayname = json['displayname'];
    instock = json['instock'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['img'] = this.img;
    data['item'] = this.item;
    data['category'] = this.category;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['uom'] = this.uom;
    data['psize'] = this.psize;
    data['price2'] = this.price2;
    data['uom2'] = this.uom2;
    data['psize2'] = this.psize2;
    data['price3'] = this.price3;
    data['uom3'] = this.uom3;
    data['psize3'] = this.psize3;
    data['vusername'] = this.vusername;
    data['displayname'] = this.displayname;
    data['instock'] = this.instock;
    return data;
  }
 static List<String> generateCombinedStrings(List<ProductDetailsUtils> data) {
    List<String> combinedList = [];
    for (var item in data) {
      String group1 = "${item.psize}  ${item.uom}";
      String group2 = "${item.psize2}  ${item.uom2}";
      String group3 = "${item.psize3}  ${item.uom3}";
      combinedList.add(group1);
      combinedList.add(group2);
      combinedList.add(group3);
    }
    return combinedList;
  }
}
```

3.api data fetching code

```
 Future<List<ProductDetailsUtils>> getAllProduct ( String pid)
  async {
    final url=Uri.parse('https://wiz-mart.com/api/prodetails.php');
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? username=prefs.getString("username");
    final queryParams = {
      'username': username,
      'pid': pid,
    };
    final newUrl = url.replace(queryParameters: queryParams);
    try{
      final response = await http.get(newUrl);
      if(response.statusCode==200)
      {
        final body= json.decode(response.body) as List;
        return body.map((e) {
          final map =e as Map<String ,dynamic>;
          return ProductDetailsUtils(
            id: map['id'],
            img: map['img'],
            item: map['item'],
            category: map['category'],
            type: map['type'],
            description: map['description'] ,
            price: map['price'] ,
            uom: map['uom'] ,
            psize: map['psize'] ,
            price2: map['price2'],
            uom2: map['uom2'] ,
            psize2: map['psize2'] ,
            price3: map['price3'] ,
            uom3: map['uom3'],
            psize3: map['psize3'] ,
            vusername:map['vusername'] ,
            displayname: map['displayname'] ,
            instock: map['instock'] ,

          );
        }).toList();
      }
      print('Login successful!');
      print(response.body);
    }catch (error) {
      print('Error occurred: $error');

    }
    throw Exception('Data Not Found');
  }
```

this is my code snapshot.